# How to clone a kentico site?

Tags: web, clone

I'm trying to clone/replicate a Kentico 6.0 Website under the same Kentico instance. I tried to export the existing site and import into a new one but it happens that when I change something in one site the other one is changing too. 
It seems that both sites are using the same databases and what I really need is 2 different sites with different databases too.

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong or does anyone had similar experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 2 different databases you need two different copies of project, each with own web.config (with own connection string).

To achieve that you can do following:

1. Export web site from existing project to a zip file, you will find it at YourProject\CMSSiteUtils\Export
2. Copy files of existing project to new location (e.g. YourProject2)
3. Navigate to web.config of newly created project and delete connection string
4. Navigate to the project from browser, it will ask you to create new database, do it
5. Move exported package to YourProject2\CMSSiteUtils\Import
6. Use Import site or objects button in CMS Site Manager -> Sites to import zip package